# Keep up SSH process when resubmitting form web.py

Tags: python, ssh, web.py, paramiko

I have got a SSH command implemented into my web.py server. When the user presses a button, a SSH command is sent to my other Raspberry Pi, which then plays a movie. However, each time the form resets itself, the movie stops playing.

How can I get Python to carry on the subprocess (SSH), even when the form has been refreshed?

Code:

```
import web
from web import form
import os
import paramiko

cmd = 'cd /media/movies'
remove_bars = 'sudo sh -c "TERM=linux setterm -foreground black -clear >/dev/tty0" '
ah = 'omxplayer -o hdmi "American Hustle.mp4" <fifo &'
nsm = 'omxplayer -o hdmi "Now You See Me.mp4" <fifo &'

def makeSSH():
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect('192.168.1.115', username='pi', password='raspberry')
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(remove_bars)
    return ssh;


# define the pages
urls = ('/', 'index')
render = web.template.render('templates')

app = web.application(urls, globals())


my_form = form.Form(
        form.Button("btn", id="btnA", value="A", html="Now You See Me", class_="btnA")
)

class index:
    # GET is used when the page is first requested
    def GET(self):
        form = my_form()
        return render.index(form, "RPi Remote Control")

    # POST is called when a web form is submitted
    def POST(self):
        # get the data submitted from the web form
        userData = web.input()

        if userData.btn == "A":
            print "TEST 1"
            ssh = makeSSH()
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(nsm)
        else:
            print "WHAT IS GOING ON?"


        raise web.seeother('/')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score -1):

I added in /media/movies/ to the movie directory, and also `time.sleep(10)` before `raise web.seeother('/')`